# Using FactoryGirl to create objects with required associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm looking for advice on how to effectively use the ruby gem 'FactoryGirl' when working with objects that have many required associated objects.

For example, say I have the following relationships between my classes.

```
class A < ActiveRecord
  has_many B
end

class B < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to A
  has_many C
end

class C < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to B
end
```

Now, if I wanted to write test cases for my C controller, I'd have to create all the objects in this chain. Right now, that's what I do in my factories. But is there a better way?

Comment: Are you asking about how to improve the code inside your factories, or are you asking how to improve your tests?

Comment: One or the other. Or both. If you know a better approach to write the factories, or a better approach to structure the tests, I would certainly appreciate learning about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have your factories set up like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :library do
    name "Chicago Public Library"
    street_address "123 Morgan St."
  end

  factory :book do
    title "A Great Book"
    author "Mandy Yeats"
    association :library
  end

  factory :page do
    page_number 123
    association :book
  end
end
```

Whenever you create an instance of :page in your tests, FactoryGirl will also create an instance of :book and :library. You don't need to create a library and a book first. If you create a :book, a :library will also be created for the test. You can use those instances in your tests like this:

```
page.book.library.name       # after using FactoryGirl.create(:page)
page.book.author

book.library.street_address  # after using FactoryGirl.create(:book)
```

This is the most straightforward way to do it that I have found.

Comment: I like this. I tried the opposite approach of creating the associations top down, where library would link to book and book would link to page. So calling FactoryGirl.create(:library) would create a library with a book and a page; but, calling book would result in only a book. The approach you are using seems much better.